# Why does django cache.set() store weird characters

Tags: django

When I save the string via django's cache framework

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set('host_cache_key_81e44325-c046-44c6-88d7-bad7cd91ec13', ""brown.example.com:8006")
```

And try to get the value out:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get :1:host_cache_key_81e44325-c046-44c6-88d7-bad7cd91ec13
"\x80\x05\x95&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\"brown.example.com:8006\x94."
```

I get some weird characters around it, why is that and how to make it not do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store the data that is stored in the cache, what you are seeing is the string serialised in the pickle format.

As an example here is the output I get when I pickle that example string

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps("brown.example.com:8006")
b'\x80\x04\x95\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x16brown.example.com:8006\x94.'
```

Comment: I see, I am trying to read the value by nginx lua, any chance to decode it in lua or not use pickle when saving to cache?

Comment: Your best best bet is to use the Redis API directly if you need to store strings readable by other programs